# ¿Como pasar una variable a la vista con VueJS Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Estoy intentando pasar un solo dato (`year`) a la vista usando vuejs.
Me funciona el arreglo en si, pero necesito pasar un solo dato.

controlador:

```php
$anno=$year;

return Inertia::render('Persona/Index',[
  'persona' => $persona,
  'comune' => $comune,
  'isee' => $isee,
  'anno' => $anno,
]);
```

y la vista

```
<template #header>
  <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">Persone, con ISEE aggiornato anno: {{anno}}</h2>
</template>
```

Comment: Hola Aty, en Blade Templates la sintaxis correcta es `{{ $anno }}`

Comment: Definiste `props` en el script? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/frontend#inertia